# gitignore all files (specific filetype) in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

What's the right way to ignore a certain filetype in a certain directory and all subdirectories in it?

Example: ignore all `.xml` files in `master/xyz/` and all subdirectories in `master/xyz/`.

I'm not sure which of the following two approaches is the right one...

```
master/xyz/*/*.xml

master/xyz/**/*.xml
```

Which one should I use?

(I use Git 1.9.1)

Comment: This question is different from the linked one, as here also ignoring inside "subdirectories" is requested.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add something like this, it will work as of git 1.8.2.1 (documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format))

> A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.

```
# should work
master/xyz/**/*.xml
```

The first suggestion you posted won't work as it will not match anything (as it is a literal)

```
# wont work
master/xyz//.xml
```

Comment: what about this approach?

    gs/html-data/partner/*.html

Comment: Sure, that will ignore all html files in gs/html-data/partner. Is that what you're after?

Comment: including all subdirs, right?

Comment: No, the /**/ is required. You would need gs/html-data/partner/**/*.html to achieve this.